# Create and loop through an array of JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have googled on this and there is nothing on the internet similar to what I'm trying to do. I'm actually now thinking if I'm tackling this issue in the right way as I have spent so much of time to resolve it.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a JFrame on which I have a JTabbedMenu assigned to the left of the frame. When I click on the menu item it displays the  relevant JPanel on the right.

To create the tabs on the left hand menu, I loop through a HashMap like this:

```
for (Entry<String, AbstractBasePanelView> menu : menuItems.entrySet()) {
    addTab(menu.getKey(), menu.getValue());
}
```

the **menuItems** HashMap is constructed like this:

```
for (Menu menu : Menu.values()) {
    menuItems.put(menu.getName(), Menu.lookup(menu.getName()).getInstance());
}
```

where Menu is an Enum class and the getInstance() method returns a new instance of the class extending the AbstractBasePanelView. The AbstractBasePanelView class extends JPanel.

Now my question is how can I add JScrollPane to each panel on the right. So that it displays a vertical scrollbar only for the JPanel where elements of that Panel stretch beyond the dimension of the JFrame.

I thought I could do something like this when I create my tabs:

```
JScrollPane[] scrollPane = new JScrollPane[menuItems.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Entry<String, AbstractBasePanelView> menu : menuItems.entrySet()) {
    scrollPane[i].getViewport().add(menu.getValue());
    addTab(menu.getKey(), scrollPane[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

But I get a runtime exception as soon as I run my application:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The exception is thrown on the line when I add the JPanel: **scrollPane[i].getViewport().add(menu.getValue());**

when I don't use an array of JScrollPane, I don't get any NullPointerException.

The below works fine but doesn't solve my purpose because the left menu appears fine but the JPanels are all empty.

```
for (Entry<String, AbstractBasePanelView> menu : menuItems.entrySet()) {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(menu.getValue());
    addTab(menu.getKey(), scrollPane);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here and how I can resolve it? A code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's a `JTabbedMenu`?  If you're getting a NPE, you need to ascertain what's actually `null` is it `scrollPane[i]` or `menu` or `menu.getValue()`. There's not enough context available to for us to be able to help you. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You're asking about 4 questions, 3 of which could be answered individually in isolation independent of your overall problem. I'd focus on asking a single question to start with

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer and it's a LOL moment for me. I completely ignored the error and was looking everywhere else. You are right, I was getting NPE on `scrollPane[i]`. I wasn't instantiating the JScrollPane. All I had to do was `scrollPane[i] = new JScrollPane(menu.getValue());`. I was just adding the panels to the JScrollPane without instantiating it. Thanks a lot and much appreciated.